# Error scraping immobilienscout24.de (empty variable)

Tags: html, windows, web-scraping, autoit

My AutoIt script scrapes www.immobilienscout24.de but only works when data is available. If the owner of a property did not provide an address it will error and crash:

```
If FileExists("Immobilien.csv") =false Then
FileWrite("Immobilien.csv","Name;Adresse;Tel;Objekt;Ort;Baujahr;Zi;frei/vermie.;Wfl./ qm;Kaltmiete;Warmmietpreis;Scout- ID"& @CRLF)
EndIf

#include <Inet.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <String.au3>
Global $mobil_A= "0"
Global $telefon_A = "0"
Global $url = InputBox("ScoutID","Enter the Scout-ID")
Global $content = _INetGetSource($url)
Global $name_A = _StringBetween($content, '<span data-qa="contactName" class="font-bold">', '</span>')
Global $preis_A = _StringBetween($content, ' "offerPrice": "', '",')
Global $strase_A = _StringBetween($content, '<strong class="font-standard">' , '</strong><br/>')
Global $telefon_A = _StringBetween($content, '<div class="is24-phone-number hide">' ,'</div>')
Global $objekttyp_A = _StringBetween($content, '<dd class="is24qa-wohnungstyp">' ,'</dd>')
Global $ort_A = _StringBetween($content, '</strong><br/>' , '<br/>')
Global $baujahr_A = _StringBetween($content, '<dd class="is24qa-baujahr">','</dd>')
Global $zimmer_A = _StringBetween($content, '<dd class="is24qa-zimmer">','</dd>')
Global $bezugsfrei_A = _StringBetween($content, '<dd class="is24qa-bezugsfrei-ab">' ,'</dd>')
Global $wohnflache_A = _StringBetween($content, '<dd class="is24qa-wohnflaeche-ca">' ,'</dd>')
Global $preiswarm_A =_StringBetween($content, '<strong class="is24qa-gesamtmiete">','</strong>')

$aio= $name_A[0]&";"&$strase_A[0]&";"&$telefon_A[0]&";"&$objekttyp_A[0]&";"&$ort_A[0]&";"&$baujahr_A[0]&";"&$zimmer_A[0]&";"&$bezugsfrei_A[0]&";"&$wohnflache_A[0]&";"&$preis_A[0]&",00"&";"&$preiswarm_A[0]&";"&$url

$sString1 = StringReplace($aio, " ", "") 
$sString2 = StringReplace($sString1, "<p>", "") 
$sString3 = StringReplace($sString2, "<span>Mobil:</span>", "") 
$sString4 = StringReplace($sString3, "</p>", "") 
$sString5 = StringReplace($sString4, "Â", "") 
$sString6 = StringReplace($sString5, '<spanclass="is24-operator">=</span>', "") 
$sString7 = StringReplace($sString6, "EUR", "") 
$sString8 = StringReplace($sString7, "<span>Telefon:</span>","")
$sStringfinal = StringReplace($sString8, @CRLF, "")

FileWrite ( "Immobilien.csv", $sStringfinal & @CRLF )
```

Examples:

- http://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/78295011
- http://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/78294144

For the first one it doesn't return anything (no address available). For the second one it works fine (returns "Viktor-Scheffel-Str. 13"). How to skip not existing values or bypass the error? The error :

```
"C:\Users\assistent02\Desktop\ExportALPHA.au3" (27) : ==> Subscript used on non-accessible variable.:
$aio= $name_A[0]&";"&$strase_A[0]&";"&$telefon_A[0]&";"&$objekttyp_A[0]&";"&$ort_A[0]&";"&$baujahr_A[0]&";"&$zimmer_A[0]&";"&$bezugsfrei_A[0]&";"&$wohnflache_A[0]&";"&$preis_A[0]&",00"&";"&$preiswarm_A[0]&";"&$url
$aio= $name_A[0]&";"&$strase_A^ ERROR
->14:43:22 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:1
+>14:43:22 AutoIt3Wrapper Finished.
>Exit code: 1    Time: 2.667
```

Comment: You should follow the AutoIt Tutorials and read some of the example codes in the documentation before asking such a basic question... The documentation is really great.

Answer (score 0):

Man, an if-else statement it's enough.
Check the documentation for the condition in the if clause: 
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_StringBetween.htm

Comment: I got it working: #include <Inet.au3> #include <Array.au3> #include <String.au3> Global $url = InputBox("ScoutID","Enter the Scout-ID") Global $content = _INetGetSource($url) Global $strase_A = _StringBetween($content, '<strong class="font-standard">' , '</strong><br/>') If  IsArray($strase_A) Then MsgBox(0,"INCLUDING","IT'S GIVEN") $strase_B = $strase_A[0] Else MsgBox(0,"NOT INCLUDING","Not given...") $strase_B = "/" EndIf MsgBox(0,"",$strase_B)

Comment: Yes, you have to surround some error checking. If the function StringBetween "fails" then you cannot access the array[0] because it is not there.